# ListView элемент "заливается"

Tags: android, xml

При нажатии на элемент списка(listview) происходит то, что показано на скрине(не знаю, как сформулировать). Из-за чего так делается, и как это починить?
Код listview

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0px"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:listSelector="#f0f1f2"/>
```

Код drawer_list_item, который используется:

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.co m/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?
android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textColor="#2e3033"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:minHeight="?
android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Поищите в других xml файлах строчку с прописанным цветом, при создании Drawer там куча файлов создается, скорее всего где-то в них есть настройки цвета выделения и прочее.

Comment: Ну listSelector есть только в main, где listview